# Show installed packages, hidding auto-installed dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, package

I want to display what package I manually installed, hiding all dependencies. Instead of having ~50 packages shown in my list.

I have installed spyder and pandas, so I would like a command like this...

> conda install --do_something

... to return a result like this

- python
- pip
- spyder
- pandas

... instead of this mess

[image]

Just to make it clear, if I were to open someone else's install (most likely my own in 2 months from now) I would like to know exactly what the human wanted to install, to get the intent.

I already looked into the documentation but didn't find what I was looking for.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: I don''t think packages that are "intentionally" installed are distinguished in any way.  Think you'd have to grep for import in the source files.

Comment: "grep for import in the source files"? Which source files are you talking about? So you could technically do it, couldn't you? If it's simple enough, we may want to send it to conda's devs for the next update. :)

Comment: You could use pipdeptree to create a ```requirements.txt``` file which could give you all of your "human installed" packages. Link: https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/

Comment: That shall do the trick! Of course, leaves are all going to be the "intentionally installed" module.  Thank you @george.adams1 ! If you want you can make an answer of your own (for those sweet sweet points), else I'll make it for you. thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pipdeptree to do create a `requirements.txt` file and have all of your "human installed" packages show up.

Link: https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/

Make sure to `pip install pipdeptree` and then you can use `pipdeptree -f | tee locked-requirements.txt` in your command line to make the `requirements.txt` file. Make sure to check out the docs linked above because they can provide some other useful tools that you can use :)

Comment: If looking for leaves only: pipdeptree --freeze  --warn silence | grep -P '^[\w0-9\-=.]+'

Comment: @FlorianFasmeyer do you have Telegram? If so, please add me ```george_adams1```. I'd like to ask you a few questions!

Comment: Sure thing! I sent you a message.